# How do I get a user input and pass it to another fragment in Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-fragments

In one of my activities in my app,

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_user_input);

    idInput = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.user_id_input);

    submitButton = (Button) findViewById((R.id.submit_button));
    submitButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            githubID = idInput.getText().toString();
        }
    });

}
```

I created a part where user can input a String called 'githubID'. I am trying to submit this to another fragment called profile_tab where the github API URL gets parsed and used for displaying the information of the user. The profile_tab looks like:

```
public class ProfileTab extends Fragment{

    // URL of the Github API to be parsed
    final String APIURL = "https://api.github.com/users/" + userID;

    // All TextView data to be displayed on the profile_tab layout
    ...

    // Data for the profile(avatar) image
    ...

    // ViewPager for navigating to another tab
    private ViewPager viewPager;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ...
```

How can I get the input string from the first page and then pass the value into the ProfileTab page and replace the 'userID' String?

**EDIT:**

**UserInput.java**

```
public class UserInput extends AppCompatActivity {

    String githubID;

    EditText idInput;

    Button submitButton;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_user_input);

        idInput = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.user_id_input);

        submitButton = (Button) findViewById((R.id.submit_button));

        SharedDataUtils.createSP(this, idInput.getText().toString());

        submitButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                githubID = idInput.getText().toString();
                Intent intent = new Intent(UserInput.this, MainActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("flag", 1);
                startActivity(intent);

            }
        });
    }

}
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private FragmentManager fragmentManager;
    private FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction;

    private SectionsPageAdapter pageAdapter;
    private ViewPager viewPager;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();

        Intent intent = getIntent();

        int flag = intent.getIntExtra("flag", -1);
        if(flag > 0) {
            if(flag == 1) {
                fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.layout, ProfileTab);
            }
        }


        pageAdapter = new SectionsPageAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

        // Sets up the ViewPager with the sections adapter

        viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.container);
        setupViewPager(viewPager);

        TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager((viewPager));
    }

    // Adds fragments to SectionsPageAdapter and gives names for the corresponding tab

    private void setupViewPager(ViewPager viewPager) {
        SectionsPageAdapter adapter = new SectionsPageAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        adapter.addFragment(new ProfileTab(), "Profile");
        adapter.addFragment(new GithubTab(), "Github Repos");
        adapter.addFragment(new FollowerTab(), "Followers");
        adapter.addFragment(new FollowingTab(), "Followings");
        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

}
```

**ProfileTab.java (fragment that parses Json)**

```
public class ProfileTab extends Fragment{

    // URL of the Github API to be parsed
    private String APIURL;
    private String userID;

    // All TextView data to be displayed on the profile_tab layout
    private TextView githubID;
    private TextView numRepos;
    private TextView numFollowers;
    private TextView numFollowings;
    private TextView userBio;
    private TextView userWebsite;
    private TextView userName;
    private TextView createdDate;

    // Data for the profile(avatar) image
    private ImageView avatarImage;
    private String avatarURL;
    Bitmap imageBitmap;

    // ViewPager for navigating to another tab
    private ViewPager viewPager;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       ... code hidden ...
    }
```

Here is what I did after looking at your help and I am getting an error in MainActivity.java on

```
    int flag = intent.getIntExtra("flag", -1);
    if(flag > 0) {
        if(flag == 1) {
            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.layout, ProfileTab);
        }
    }
```

Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**1.Create `SharedPreferenceUtils` to save and get data**

```
public class SharedPreferenceUtils {

    private static final String SP_NAME = "sp";
    public static final String USER_ID = "userId";


    // create
    public static boolean createSP(Context context, String userId) {
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = context.getSharedPreferences(SP_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
        editor.putString(USER_ID, userId);
        return editor.commit();
    }


    // get userID
    public static String getUserId(Context context) {
        SharedPreferences sp = context.getSharedPreferences(SP_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        return sp.getString(USER_ID, "");
    }
}
```

**2.Sava data in the `Activity`**

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_user_input);

    idInput = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.user_id_input);

    submitButton = (Button) findViewById((R.id.submit_button));
    // edited here ,create and save useId
    SharedPreferenceUtils.createSP(this, idInput.getText().toString());
    submitButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            githubID = idInput.getText().toString();
            // edited here
            Intent intent = new Intent(UserInputActivity.this, YourNextActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("flag", 1);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
}
```

**3.get data in `Fragment`**

```
private String APIURL;
private String userID;

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ...
    // edited here , get userId 
    userID = SharedPreferenceUtils.getUserId(getActivity());
    APIURL = "https://api.github.com/users/" + userID;
}
```

**4.`NextActivity`**

```
private FragmentManager fmanager;
private FragmentTransaction ftransaction;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_your_next);
    fmanager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    ftransaction = fmanager.beginTransaction();

    Intent intert = getIntent();
    int flag = intert.getIntExtra("flag", -1);
    if (flag > 0) {
        System.out.println("flag" + flag);
        if (flag == 1) {
            // go to fragment
            ftransaction.replace(R.id.layout, yourFrgament); 
        }
    }
}
```

**EDIT**

```
// position is the fragment you want to go 
TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
tabLayout.setupWithViewPager((viewPager));
int flag = intent.getIntExtra("flag", -1);
if(flag > 0) {
    if(flag == 1) {
        viewPager.setCurrentItem(your_tab_position);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! But I actually forgot to ask how can I immediately move to the fragment that I am sending data to after I click the button?

Comment: The `Fragment` is in current activity or next activity .

Comment: The next activity.

Comment: So this is what's happening. I have a MainActivity.java that contains a ViewPager and a TabLayout which has four different tabs. In the question, I wanted to pass in the input String to one of the tab fragments that handles parsing the Github API. I want it to make my userID passed into the Profile_tab which is part of MainActivity's TabLayout.

Comment: You can check it .

Comment: Do I have to add mViewPager.setCurrentItem(position); in the NextActivity?

Comment: Wait, so is the EDIT supposed to be in the NextActivity?

Comment: YES .You should add in it .

Comment: It runs without an error, but when I type in the user ID, it moves to the profile Tab, but no data is parsed.

Comment: Could you add `userID = SharedPreferenceUtils.getUserId(getActivity());
    APIURL = "https://api.github.com/users/" + userID;` to your fragment ?

Comment: You can check the code .And could you use the code I provided ?